# Raw type/ T cannot be resolved

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I started working with generics for Java and seem to be missing a key component.

First off, I did some reading on raw type needing parameters and realize there is not much to do since they are generic but my problem is the interaction between `BagInterface` and `LinkedBag`:

```
package Chapter3;

public interface BagInterface<T> {

/** Gets the current number of entries in the bag.
* @return the integer number of entries in the bag. */
public int getCurrentSize();

/** Sees whether this bag is full.
*@return true if the bag is full, or false if not. */
public boolean isFull();

/** Sees whether the bag is empty.
*@return true if bag is empty, or false if not. */
public boolean isEmpty();

/** Adds new entry to this bag.
*@param newEntry the object to be added as a new entry
*@return if the addition was successful, or false if not. */
public boolean add(T newEntry);

/** Removes one unspecified entry from this bag, if possible.
*@return either the removed entry, if the removal was successful, or null. */
public T remove();

/** Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this bag.
*@param anEntry the entry to be removed
*@return true id the removal was successful, or false if not. */
public boolean removal(T anEntry);

/** Removes all entries from this bag. */
public void clear();

/** Counts the number of times a given entry appears in this bag.
*@param anEntry the entry to be counted
*@return the number of times anEntry appears in the bag. */
public int getFrequencyOf(T anEntry);

/** Tests whether this bag contains a given entry.
*@param anEntry the entry to locate
*@return true if this bag contains anEntry, or false if not. */
public boolean contains(T anEntry);

/**Retrieves all entries that are in this bag.
*@return a newly allocated array of all the entries in the bag */
public T[] toArray();
}
```

the two errors have to do with T not being resolved

```
package Chapter3;

public class LinkedBag  implements BagInterface { 

// reference to first node
private Node firstNode;
private int numberOfEntries;

// default constructor
public LinkedBag() {

firstNode = null;
numberOfEntries = 0;
}

// second constructor
(error occurs here) public LinkedBag(T[] item, int numberOfItems) {
this();
for(int index = 0; index < numberOfItems; index++)
add(item[index]);
}`
```

the other being being with get.data but i believe that also has to do with T not resolving

```
(error occurs here) result[index] = currentNode.getData();
index++;
currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
}// end while
return result;
}// end is full
```

I have the full .java files transcribed to note if more info is needed but I tried to keep it specific and concise.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you share their exact text?

Comment: errors on T are  

"T cannot be resolved to a type"

errors on getData()
"The method getData() from the type LinkedBag.Node refers to the missing type T"

Comment: What line produces this error?

Comment: public LinkedBag(T[] item, int numberOfItems) {

result[index] = currentNode.getData();

anywhere T is referenced in this class and .getData()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedBag` in the code you shared, implements the raw `BagInterface`. If you want to refer to its type specification, you should add type argument to `LinkedBag` too, and have it refer to the `BagInterface` type somehow. E.g.:

```
public class LinkedBag<T>  implements BagInterface<T> { 
// Here --------------^---------------------------^
```

Comment: thank you I, was working on this last night and hit that wall, i am at work so i am unable to test it but i will do so and see if my problem is solved.. i though maybe i just wasn't linking the classes together but they exist in the same package( again my knowledge of compilers is also limited)

 only started using eclipse this semester